# Can LinqPad read an XML comment on a static field during autocomplete?

Tags: c#, xml, autocomplete, comments, linqpad

I have a static class with many static fields that represent math functions. For example, in a class "Integer", I have properties such as "GreaterThan", "Add", etc. that represent functions related to integers.

This environment is used by non-developer users (i.e. with no access to the source code and comments) in Linqpad to build ad-hoc functions and queries. I'd like to add XML comments to these fields to explain what data types they return, and what the types of the parameters are, and have those comments show up in Linqpad's auto-complete.  For example, the Integer "Log" function takes 2 params, a value and a base, but for the end users it's not easy for them to tell which is which without comments (or cheating and looking at the source code). "Does the base come first or second?", etc.

I have not been able to figure out how to get the XML comments on the field to show up in Linqpad auto-complete. Elsewhere in my codebase, I have C# interface methods (not properties) with XML comments on them, and once I turned the "Output XML documentation file" option on in Visual Studio in the project properties, they show up in LinqPad (at least, I can see the "summary" tag in the LinqPad autocomplete window).

On an interface method, this works and "Execute a query" appears in Linqpad auto-complete:

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute a query
/// </summary>
void Execute(Query query);
```

But for a static field like this, I don't see the summary text appear in Linqpad auto-complete:

```
/// <summary>
/// Log function (returns a float, first param is value, second is base)
/// </summary>
public static Function Log = new Function("Log", DataType.Float, DataType.Integer, DataType.Float);
```

Does anyone know if Linqpad supports documenting static fields in this way, and if so, how to get it to show up in the auto-complete?

I am using LinqPad version 4.47.02 currently.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I was incorrectly calling them "properties", but I should have said "static field" instead. Thanks to sgmoore for the correction.

Comment: I don't know myself, but have you tried asking on the [LINQPad Forum](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussions)?

Comment: Are you sure your xml file is getting built correctly and is in the folder that LinqPad is referencing? This works for me using the same version of Linqpad. By the way your example is showing a static field rather than a property. I have had issues with information missing from some properties, but any time I checked the xml comments were identical or almost identical to the property name, so I assumed it was deliberate.

Comment: @sgmoore I believe so, before I turned on the "generate XML doc" option in Visual Studio, I wasn't getting ANY auto-complete hints in LinqPad, but once I did, I get the "summary" XML comment on interface methods showing up, so at least I know that's working. Also, you are right, I think I'm using the wrong terminology (property instead of field) for the static. I'll update the question.